# os::commit_memory failed; error=Not enough space (errno=12)

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, ubuntu

I have a spring boot application running on ubuntu 20 ec2 machine where I am creating around 200000 threads to write data into kafka. However it is failing repeatedly with the following error

```
[138.470s][warning][os,thread] Attempt to protect stack guard pages failed (0x00007f828d055000-0x00007f828d059000).
[138.470s][warning][os,thread] Attempt to deallocate stack guard pages failed.
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: [138.472s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00007f828cf54000, 16384, 0) failed; error='Not enough space' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 16384 bytes for committing reserved memory.
```

I have tried increasing memory of my ec2 instance to 64 gb which have been of no use. I am using docker stats and htop to monitor the memory footprint of the process and when it touches around 10 gb it fails with the given error.

I have also tried increasing the heap size and max memory for the process.

```
docker run --rm --name test -e JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx64g -v /workspace/logs/test:/logs -t test:master
```

Below is my code

```
    final int LIMIT = 200000;
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(LIMIT);
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(LIMIT);
    for (int i = 1; i <= LIMIT; i++) {
        final int counter = i;
        executorService.execute(() -> {
            try {
                kafkaTemplate.send("rf-data", Integer.toString(123), "asdsadsd");
                kafkaTemplate.send("rf-data", Integer.toString(123), "zczxczxczxc");
                latch.countDown();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error sending data: ", e);
            }
        });
    }
    try {
        latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        logger.error("error ltach", e);
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `-Xmx` if using Java 11+. Instead, set the `--memory` of the container, and the JVM will resize accordingly

Comment: Thread stacks aren't in the heap, so increasing the heap limit makes no difference. (If it did, you would need over 200G of survivor space, probably 250G total.)

Answer (score 0):

In docker compose yml file, you can modify the memory limit of a container.
You could try to increase that limit, in your image configuration section, as follows:

```
  ...
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: <memory size>
```

More info [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#limit-a-containers-access-to-memory)